# Jquery validation identy card number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to validate a field for bellow type only
`158964236V` or `258963478952`.
This is my code.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkformat", function(value, element)
    {
        return  /^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/.test(value);
    }, 'Invalid National Identity Card Number');
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: your question is not clear, please explain properly what are you expecting

Comment: I need to validate for only these type of input 0-9 digit with V or 0-12 digit only

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below regex -

```
^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$|^[0-9]{1,12}$
```

Your Code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkformat", function(value, element)
    {
        return  /^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$|^[0-9]{1,12}$/.test(value);
    }, 'Invalid National Identity Card Number');
```

**Description**:

**1st Alternative** `^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$`

`^` asserts position at start of the string;

Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{9};

`{9}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 9 times;

`0-9` a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive);

Match a single character present in the list below [vVxX];

`vVxX` matches a single character in the list vVxX (case sensitive);

`$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any);

**2nd Alternative** `^[0-9]{1,12}$`

`^` asserts position at start of the string;

Match a single character present in the list below `[0-9]{1,12}`;

`{1,12}` Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 12 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy);

`0-9` a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive);

`$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any);

Note: You can test your regex here - https://regex101.com/